# Regex to Capture Specific 8-digit String in Variable using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

In my Perl script, I have a variable that contains a specific file path. I need to create a regular expression that can capture a specific 8-digit string from that variable.

When `$file_path = "/home/attachments/00883227/sample.txt`
I want to capture the string of numbers immediately following "attachments".

My (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
if($file_path =~ /attachments\/(\d{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}+)/)
    { $number = $1; }
```

When I run this script, though, it looks like nothing is stored in the $number variable. The solution for this is probably very simple? Please pardon my ignorance, I am very new to Perl.

Comment: The [matching repetition section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions) in `perldoc perlretut` should be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close, just use `(\d{8})`, like:

```
$file_path =~ /attachments\/(\d{8})\b/
```

Also added `\b` so that it doesn't capture any longer numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- works perfectly! I like the \b as well.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to give so much of numbers in the braces. Simply use `{8}` to enforce matching of 8 digits. And since you have `/` inside your string, you can use a different delimiter, instead of escaping the slashes:

```
if($file_path =~ m!attachments/(\d{8})!)
   { $number = $1; }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match exactly 8 digits, just use `\d{8}`:

```
if($file_path =~ /attachments\/(\d{8})/)
    { $number = $1; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my ($number) = ( $file_path =~ m{ (attachments/( [0-9]{8} ) }x );
```

Using pattern delimiters other than `/` such as `m{ }`, you avoid the so-called *leaning toothpick syndrome* caused by the need to escape and `/` characters that appear in the pattern.

By assigning to `$number` in list context, the captured substring goes into `$number` immediately.

By using the `x` option, you make your pattern somewhat more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
if($file_path =~ /attachments\/(\d+)/)
{ $number = $1; }
```

`{ , }` is used to limit the number of times a certain character (or group of characters) to repeat. `{n,m}` means that the character (or group) should repeat at least n times and at most m times.

If you're certain the string of digits is 8-digits long, you then use:

```
if($file_path =~ /attachments\/(\d{8})/)
{ $number = $1; }
```

`{ }` (without commas) will match exactly the number specified.

Comment: You forgot the 8 digit requirement.

Comment: @Barmar The OP used `+` in their regex, which didn't quite agree with what they were saying, though I guess it could be quite natural if the  OP doesn't know about regex that much...

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($number) = $file_path =~ m{attachments/(\d+)};
```

If you want to ensure it's exactly eight digits long,

```
my ($number) = $file_path =~ m{attachments/(\d{8})(?!\d)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply give the limits.

like, \d{3,8} where it will return digits between 3-8 length.

Answer (score 0):

Is it going to be exactly 8 digits or between 1 to 8 digits?

Since you're looking at `/attachments/` as a piece of the string, you probably don't want to use the standard `/../` delimiters. Maybe switching to `m{..}` or `m#..#`:

```
if ( $file_path =~ m#/attachments/\(d{1,8})/# ) {
```

That will capture between 1 to 8 digits. To capture exactly 8:

```
my $number;
if ( $file_path =~ m#/attachments/(\d{8})/# ) {
   $number = $1;
   ...
}
else {
    ....
}
```

Note that I define `$digit_string` before the `if` statement. This way, it's in scope after the `if` statement (and inside the `if` statement. (You are using `use strict;`? Right?)